# What is the difference between JQuery MarginRight and CSS margin-right used in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the difference between **JQuery marginRight** and using **CSS margin-right** property in Javascript?

*With **marginRight** I can do things like this...*

```
$("button").click(function () {
      var div = $("div");
      div.animate({ marginRight: '4em', opacity: '0.4' }, "slow");
});
```

*Some manipulations I can do with either...*

```
$(".element").css("marginRight") = "4em";

$(".element").css("margin-right") = "4em";
```

Why has jQuery allowed style manipulation like marginRight as well as margin-right? Doesn't it use more resources to converted to the **CSS margin-right** from **jQuery** **marginRight**?

How do you decide when which usage is appropriate?

Comment: CSS property with a `-` is written as camel cased property when used in Javascript. So both are essentially the same property.

Comment: What might be interesting to check is whether one is faster than the other. Is jQuery doing something behind the scenes (regex?) that might optimize camelCase over hyphen separated? Or, vice versa? Here's a quick `jsperf` I threw together http://jsperf.com/camelcase-vs-hyphen which shows camelCase is faster than hyphen (in Chrome, at least)

Comment: @JackPattishallJr.: As with so many things, this will hardly have any relevance in practice …

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. : I updated your `jsperf` to add underscore system.  It seems to be faster in Chrome. http://jsperf.com/camelcase-vs-hyphen/2. I did not expect that result though.

Comment: @CBroe - while that's true, it could at least help a dev justify their implementation decision between the various choices. or, something to share in those meetings where you discuss performance opt techniques with your team... (those are always fun...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are the same, jQuery understands both formats. [From the docs:](https://api.jquery.com/css/#entry-longdesc)

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both `.css( "background-color" )` and `.css(
>   "backgroundColor" )`.

These two syntax's to access these css properties already exist outside jQuery. For example:

In CSS:

```
#elm {margin-right: value;}
```

In vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById('elm').style.marginRight = value;
```

Supporting both syntax's would be required to keep both camps happy and to maintain existing paradigms.

As for speed I would suggest [although I haven't done tests] that the camel cased version would be quicker because that's how they would be setting/getting these values internally.

@jack-pattishall-jr made a jsperf -> http://jsperf.com/camelcase-vs-hyphen

Answer (score 0):

Some people prefers CamelCase (marginRight), some other prefers hyphenated system (margin-right).

I think everything is about the naming convention of your project. That's all.

Read this [intersting post](http://blog.ricky-stevens.com/css-element-naming-conventions/).

As far as I understood, hyphenated system is the CSS native system. But as others languages (like javascript or php) do not support hyphens in variables name, CamelCase is a good alternative to make developpement simpler.

And to really answer your question : I don't think this is a big deal for jQuery, but as it should probably modify javascript style property, I guess it finally uses CamelCase at the end. But I assume it does not check for hyphens in the name before converting, it probably always goes through the convert function to do this. So I don't think one is quicker than an otherone.

---

EDIT : What I mean by 'naming convention of the project' is that the time you may gain on choosing one solution for a given language can be lost in converting operations for an other. I guess CamelCase resolve this issue, event it is not the native system in pure CSS.